# How to change Rails default generated views directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to set the default generated views directory in a Rails app. For example, if I run `rails g controller foo index`, I'd like the generated views directory and files be in `app/views/controllers/foo` instead of the default Rails path of `app/views/foo`.

Comment: that doesn't really make sense. if you want to namespace your views/controllers you need to run `rails g controller controllers/foo index` but that will also namespace your controller. your `app/controllers/*` have to correspond to your `app/views/*`

Comment: I'm not trying to namespace the controller, just trying to put the generated views in a different directory by default. I've looked at customizing the generator, but can't seem to find a way to change the default views directory.

Comment: You are trying to fight a rails core principal [Convention over Configuration](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine#convention-over-configuration), this will only make your life more difficult. Also take a look at how [`zietwerk`](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#autoloading) handles autoloading.

Comment: I would think if Rails allows setting the default view path via a [class method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#method-i-append_view_path), it would allow changing the default generated views path as well.

Comment: `app/views` is hardcoded, so you have to patch the generator https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/controller/controller_generator.rb#L11